# Why is my powershell script unable to create a folder in C:\Program Files?

Tags: windows, powershell, vbscript, cmd

I am trying to create a script which will create a directory in the C:\Program Files folder.

I am able to run the line to create it fine when I run in via an elevated powershell prompt manually - however when I run it via a script (elevated still) **it simply creates a "file" object with the name I want instead of a folder.**

Here is the code I am using to write the folder:

```
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path "C:\Program Files\Info"
```

I have also tried simply copying a folder into the Program Files location, with the same results.

Is there anyway I can script this so it will work?

I have found an old vbscript which does work to create the folder, so there must be a way to accomplish this in Powershell!?

Thanks for your time

Comment: Can you please add the error that it returns?

Comment: `-ItemType` -> `-Type`

Comment: It does not give an error, it simply creates a "file" type unknown object with the name of the folder I wanted

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen `-ItemType` works in POSH 5.x.x.x    not sure about older versions

Comment: See if you can add a folder manually in that location,I feel it may be permission issue

Comment: Actually I just figured it out - I thought I was going crazy for such a stupidly simple task! 

There was a Copy-Item block of code I just found that was listed before the directory was actually being created. This produced the odd side effect of creating an object of "file" type and not a directory as expected!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was actually my mistake, before creating the directory there was a block of code with Copy-Item to the non-existent directory ***without the trailing slash***, which produced the result in which instead of the parent folder being created as expected, a file with the folder name was created, with the type "file".

Creating the directory before copying items solved the issue. (Or including the trailing slashed and forcing the New-Item might have worked also)

Hopefully this might be useful to someone in the future!